# wordpress page links not working it says page not found

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

Ive uploaded my wordperss website from one to another host everything workds perfectly. onky thing that doesnt work is page links.

this is my .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?coolkid.ge$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/gf/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /gf/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?coolkid.ge$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ gf/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

home page is working admin is working but other pages not working 
what do i need to do?

Comment: Please update permalink then it will work

Comment: If below answer working for you then let me know please

Comment: yes thanx man it worked

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps

1. Try flushing your mod_rewrite rules:
2. Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks
3. Save settings (no need to make any changes)

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks and click save 
after that remove cache and check. site pages

[image]